# Store the output from SSMS query/script for SSMS Add in

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, ssms, add-in

I've created an SSMS Add in (using Visual Studio 2010 (C#)) that stores the SQL script that has been executed to a text file on the local machine. I want to do the same with the query output but can't find any resources that cover this. Can anyone shed some light on how this would be done?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the source for T-SQL Flex, that's an open source add-in for SSMS that exports query results to Excel - I'm sure there would be some useful tips in there!

https://github.com/nycdotnet/TSqlFlex/releases

Note that it uses Redgate's SIP add-in framework, which may or may not be compatible with your aims.

Author's blog is here: http://nycdotnet.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/new-add-on-for-ssms-t-sql-flex.html

I'm not in any way affiliated with this, I just recently downloaded it and found it useful.